# How do I print these hash symbols using a loop?

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I have a loop which calculates all the prime numbers. The calculation is good but I can't figure out how to print the hash symbols before the number.  For example, here is the code I have:

```
for num in range(MIN, rangeNumber + 1):
    # Print all prime numbers
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

I am trying to figure out how I can print the `#` sign before the numbers.
Here is the output that is expected:

[image]

How can I create the `for` loop?

Comment: By the way: the term "hashtag" gets its name from the symbol "#" which is sometimes called "hash". The symbol itself is not called "hashtag".

Comment: Should I just call it the number symbol?

Comment: You can call it "hash". Or "number sign". It has many names. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a string of n #'s, just write `'#' * n`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  That works but it is not printing the number after the hashtags in the same line.

Comment: print('#' * n, n)

Comment: This works, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = 3

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print("#" * i, i)
```

```
OUTPUT:
# 1
## 2
### 3
```